# Javascript - Find single instance of a property's value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using `array.protoype.some` I am trying to find a single instance of a property's value `''` in an array of objects. If the value `''`is found then variable `round` will be `0`. Here is the codepen http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/meNeoJ?editors=101

```
$scope.cells = [ { value: '', disabled: false }, 
               { value: '', disabled: false },
               { value: '' , disabled: false}, 
               { value: '' , disabled: false },
               { value: '' , disabled: false},
               { value: '', disabled: false } ,
               { value: '' , disabled: false},
               { value: '', disabled: false }, 
               { value: '' , disabled: false} ];

function hasValue(element) {
    return element === '';
}

//check if all cells are filled
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cells.length; i++){
    if($scope.cells[i].value.some(hasValue)){
        round = 0;
    }else{
        round = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue?

Comment: What's in the array? Given a sample array of values, what output would you expect? If that information is already in the pen, then please include it here, the pen is a bonus but sufficient code to understand, and answer, the question is mandatory here on Tia site, in your question.

Comment: I need to loop through every object in `$scope.cells` and check the property `value:` of each object. If there is a single instance of `''` in the property `value` then variable `round = 0` else (if there is no `''` in the property `value` in any of the objects) then `round = 1`

Answer (score 2):

`Array.protoype.some` must be called on an array. You're calling it on `$scope.cells[i].value`, so it throws an error.

Try removing the `for` loop, and simply calling `some` on the array:

```
function hasValue(element) {
  return element.value === "";
}

if($scope.cells.some(hasValue)){
  round = 0;
}else{
  round = 1;
}
```

Comment: It was simpler than I thought. I should have added the property `.value` in the function `hasValue` rather than trying to execute it with `array.some` which it can't.